# Is "Old Black Joe" the reason coffee is known as Joe?

Tags: english-language

I was reminded recently that ‘joe’ was once a slangy term for coffee, at least in the United States (although I suspect less common than it once was). The [Wikipedia article about the origin of the phrase](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cup_of_joe) was interesting, but there didn’t seem any certitude as to where it came from.

My own guess is that it grew from the song ‘[Old Black Joe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Black_Joe)’, which was very popular for a very long time. I think that ‘joe’ usually meant black coffee, and I am sure that coffee in a greasy-spoon or a truck-stop was more often than not old!

Does anyone have information that might confirm or condemn this idea?

Thanks!